# Linux bash-script to run make in all subdirectories

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to write a bash-script in Linux which traverses the current directory and, in every subdirectory, it launches the existing makefile. It should work for each subdirectory, regardless of depth.

Some restrictions:

- I cannot use Python;
- I don't know in advance how many subdirectories and their names;
- I don't know in advance the name of current directory;
- the `make` command for each directory should only be launched if there is makefile in such folder.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: You should present what you want exactly...make examples then tell us what exactly you want

Comment: I've tried to improve your question, to make it clearer. If I changed the meaning of your post, please, edit it. Also, as pointed by MortezaLSC, add some example of what you want, and show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `-exec` and GNU [make](/questions/tagged/make)

```
find -type f \( -name 'GNUmakefile' -o -name 'makefile' -o -name 'Makefile' \) \
-exec bash -c 'cd "$(dirname "{}")" && make' \;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get an error message: `line 2: -exec: command not found`

Comment: Note that the command has no newlines. You seem to have one right before -exec.

Comment: If I use single string `find -type f -name 'GNUmakefile' -o -name 'makefile' -o -name 'Makefile' \ -exec bash -c 'cd $(dirname "{}"); make' \;` then I get an error message: `find: paths must precede expression`

Comment: @alex Make sure you're copy/pasting it directly, or just remove the escape character after `Makefile` and remove the newline. Put it in here just so it's readable here.

Comment: Big thanks! Yes, I removed only first \ and use single string and then it works: `find -type f -name 'GNUmakefile' -o -name 'makefile' -o -name 'Makefile' -exec bash -c 'cd $(dirname "{}"); make' \;`

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is make-related. I'd try to use a makefile at the top-level instead of a script. Something like this:

```
MAKEFILES:=$(shell find . -mindepth 2 -name Makefile -type f)
DIRS:=$(foreach m,$(MAKEFILES),$(realpath $(dir $(m))))

.PHONY: all
all: $(DIRS)

.PHONY: $(DIRS)
$(DIRS):
     $(MAKE) -C $@
```

I'd accept what @MLSC says about using `for` with `find`, and that kind of applies here too .. the problem with that is when you have a space in the directory name. However, in many cases that's not going to happen, and IMHO there are benefits in using a makefile instead of a script. (There might be a solution using make that can cope with spaces in the directory name, but I can't think of it off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script  https://gist.github.com/legeyda/8b2cf2c213476c6fe6e25619fe22efd0.

Example usage is:

```
foreach */ 'test -f Makefile && make'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if dont care about the execution order or if parent directory also has a Makefile.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(find . -name Makefile); do
  pushd $(dirname $f)
  make
  popd
done
```

Comment: for with find is not a good idea:

`find . -name Makefile |
while IFS= read -r dir
do
.
.
.
done`

Comment: Thanks. But I get an error message: `line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `do`

Comment: @MortezaLSC If I try to use string `find . -name Makefile | while IFS= read -r dir do` instead of `for f in $(find . -name Makefile); do` then I get an error message: `line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'done'`

Comment: You should put the code in a file and run it from your shell.

Comment: @tpatja Yes, I put it in a file `makeall.sh`, but I get this error.